# Excel VBA To login and display a set number of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trawling Stack overflow for some support and assistance and found the below code. I've changed this to my specifications. What I'm wanting the VBA code to do is when I click login I want it to search the sheet called "Access List" and confirm if the user is found in the sheet. If the user is found, display the sheets (Pull Print, Push Print, USB, Thresholds and Site contacts). Once it's completed this task, I would then like it to hide the page "Welcome".

I've been able to code this part, but the part I'm struggling with is that if a user leaves the username & password fields blank and they just click login. The message I'm seeing is

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Can someone please help me out?

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim Id As String, pw As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If Len(Trim(txtlogin)) = 0 Then
    txtlogin.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Username cannot be empty"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Trim(txtpassword)) = 0 Then
    txtpassword.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Password cannot be empty"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("Access List")
Id = LCase(Me.txtlogin)

Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=Id, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'~~> If match found
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    RowNo = aCell.Row
    If Me.txtpassword = aCell.Offset(, 1) Then
    Else
    Sheets("Home").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Sheets("Pull Print").Visible = True
    Sheets("Push Print").Visible = True
    Sheets("USB").Visible = True
    Sheets("Thresholds").Visible = True
    Sheets("Site Contacts").Visible = True
    Sheets("Access List").Visible = xlSheetHidden

        MsgBox "Unable to match UserID or PasswordID, Please try again", vbOKOnly
    End If

Else '<~~ If not found

    MsgBox "Unable to match UserID or PasswordID, Please try again", vbOKOnly

End If
CleanExit:
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inconsistently accessing the `txtlogin` field.  Sometimes using `Me.` and sometimes not.

Assuming your are within a single workbook and in a form module change this line:

```
Id = LCase(Me.txtlogin)
```

To this:

```
Id = LCase(txtlogin)
```

---

If not, change your if statements like this:

```
If Len(Trim(Me.txtlogin)) = 0 Then
   ...
If Len(Trim(Me.txtpassword)) = 0 Then
   ....
```

---

You can remove your `On Error` line to find out which line is throwing the error.

Comment: I have now changed my code to reflect this and when I click login, it's still not unhiding the pages

Answer (score 0):

If button and textboxes reside in a form, this error should not come.
Assuming those reside in a worksheet, so:

instead of:

```
txtlogin.SetFocus
txtpassword.SetFocus
```

use these:

```
txtlogin.Activate
txtpassword.Activate
```

*Appended Answer:*
So, assuming previous error is gone after using above, here is the complete thing (Mark as Answer if this what you were looking for):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim Id As String, pw As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If txtlogin.Value = "" Then
txtlogin.Activate
MsgBox "cant be empty"
Exit Sub
End If

If txtpassword.Value = "" Then
txtpassword.Activate
MsgBox "cant be empty"
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("Access List")
Id = LCase(Me.txtlogin)
'MsgBox Id
pw = Me.txtpassword

Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=Id, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'If UserID match found
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
RowNo = aCell.Row
If pw = aCell.Offset(, 1) Then
MsgBox "user : " & Id & " logged in"
txtpassword.Value = ""
txtlogin.Value = ""

'do your sheet visibility on off here, like these:
Sheets("USB").Visible = True
Sheets("Access List").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Else
txtpassword.Value = ""
MsgBox "Hello " & Id & " ,Password did not match, Please try again", vbOKOnly
txtpassword.Activate
End If

Else 'If no match found

MsgBox "Unable to match UserID, Please try again", vbOKOnly
txtlogin.Value = ""
txtpassword.Value = ""
txtlogin.Activate
'MsgBox "Wrong Password, Please try again", vbOKOnly
End If
CleanExit:
Set aCell = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I've now implemented this but now when I add people into my access list it's still not logging them in